# Google Cloud Stackdriver restrict domains

Tags: stackdriver

Can I restrict or block others from pinging my domain thru Stackdriver? I want to use it as owner of the domain but I don't want others to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to restrict users in your organization from using Stackdriver, use Cloud IAM roles, or rather, ensure they do not have the Cloud IAM role to view Stackdriver. [This](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) help you better understand IAM.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#stackdriver_debugger_roles) is a list of roles in GCP. You will likely be interested to see Stackdriver debugger, trace, logging, Error reporting, &/or monitoring roles. Ensure any user you wish to not have access to those Stackdriver tools does not have any of the roles listed under their respective tools list of roles. For example, if you wish for a user to not have access to Stackdriver debugging, ensure they do not have the "clouddebugger.agent" or "clouddebugger.user" roles.

If you would like others to not be able to access you website i.e. example.com, use [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) to block IP addresses, ports, etc.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to block users outside my organization to ping my domain from Stackdriver.

Comment: How are you able to ping your domain from Stackdriver? Also, what is your use case? There may be different options available to solve the problem